# How to split RDD of (String, Array[String]) into RDD of (String, String) for each item in array?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, scala-collections

I have a PairRDD in the form `RDD[(String, Array[String])]`. I want to flatten the values so that I have an `RDD[(String, String)]` where each of the elements in the Array[String] of the first RDD become a dedicated element in the 2nd RDD.

For instance, my first RDD has the following elements:

```
("a", Array("x", "y"))
("b", Array("y", "z"))
```

The result I want is this:

```
("a", "x")
("a", "y")
("b", "y")
("b", "z")
```

How can I do this? `flatMapValues(f: Array[String] => TraverableOnce[String])` seems to be the right choice here, but what do I need to use as argument `f`?

Comment: Just do `rdd.flatMapValues(x => x)`

Comment: @kaktusito Right thanks; I've updated the question because I was actually looking for the argument to pass into flatMapValues(). You've made that clean.

Comment: @Carsten I would use `identity` instead of `x => x`. The scala compiler is probably clever enough to realize that that's `identity` but maybe not and then you create a new object.

Comment: Is there any difference using this instead: `rdd.flatMap{ case (a,b) => b.map(a->_) }` ? Does `flatMapValues` do anything different ?

Comment: @tuxdna There's a performance reason, I believe. `flatMap` is not guaranteed to keep the partitioner of the original rdd (since there's no way to check that the keys will remain the same), while `flatMapValues` will. This is important when doing operations that require shuffling, as joins.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To achieve the desired result, do:

```
val rdd1: RDD[(Any, Array[Any])] = ...
val rddFlat: RDD[(Any, Any)] = rdd1.flatMapValues(identity[Array[Any]])
```

The result looks like the one asked for in the question.

Comment: protip: It should be a Wiki answer instead since you simply gathered the comments.